In C++, is cout<<printf("2") an undefined behavior?
The question comes from my friends, and they argued a lot about it.
The ones that think it's not UB say, obviously, printf is a function, so its side effect must happen before return value is set, and cout's side effect must happen after that.
The ones that think it's UB say, as printf differs a lot from normal functions, it may seem doubtful to suppose its side effect is always before return value is set and used.
I can't determine which of them are right. On my computer it outputs 21, as one may normally think.
Or this is an unspecified behavior instead of an undefined one?

The C++ standard doesn’t know that “printf differs a lot from normal functions” (except for some well-defined rules, such as namespacing). It’s a regular function. However, you are mixing C and C++ standard streams; depending on the value of std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(), the result may be unspecified.

Why do you/they think this can be UB? What is the argument to support it? Here you have nice list of all UBs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/367662/1387438

BTW do they mention this can happen after disabling synchronization with stdio: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio

If you're talking about competition code, your mileage will vary, but for production code you're probably grinding too hard for extra performance if you need to worry playing mix-n-match with IO.

cout<<printf("2") is well-defined. It will call printf which will print the string "2". Then printf returns a value, which will be printed to std::cout.
Basically it's equivalent to:
int result = printf("2");  // Printing one character, result will be 1
cout << result;


I wonder how this qualifies in case of std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);. In such case outcome is not well defined. I think this is actually UB, but can't find good link to document it.
